# jst:compile destination not written because compiled files were empty

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, mustache

I got this error after NetBeans crashed while working with Backbone and Mustache templating. I use "grunt server" to load and test the application.

In the console (chrome) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'app/scripts/templates/App.mustache' of undefined
```

Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes, maybe a hundred times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found what I was doing wrong. I'll post my solution, in case someone happens to have the same problem.

I had everything correctly installed, and I was using yeoman as scaffolder, but when I created the project I did:

```
yo backbone
```

Instead, if you plan to use 'mustache' templates, you should scaffold the project using:

```
yo backbone --template-framework=mustache
```

Here is the reference https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone